# getting error installing python package brypt and cffi on raspbian stretch

Tags: python, bcrypt, python-cffi, cffi

I am trying to install brypt that has dependency on cffi,

but this is landing into the error shown below:

```
$ pip install bcrypt
Collecting bcrypt
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/91/a5/fd19eac0252e56b4ce65ced937ae40024782c21108da7d830003b7f76cdb/bcrypt-3.1.5.tar.gz
Collecting cffi>=1.1 (from bcrypt)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e7/a7/4cd50e57cc6f436f1cc3a7e8fa700ff9b8b4d471620629074913e3735fb2/cffi-1.11.5.tar.gz
Collecting six>=1.4.1 (from bcrypt)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/73/fb/00a976f728d0d1fecfe898238ce23f502a721c0ac0ecfedb80e0d88c64e9/six-1.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pycparser (from cffi>=1.1->bcrypt)
  Using cached https://www.piwheels.org/simple/pycparser/pycparser-2.19-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Building wheels for collected packages: bcrypt, cffi
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for bcrypt ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-aWg7sM/bcrypt/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpgmKbFipip-wheel- --python-tag cp27:
  Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
  Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
  to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
  No package 'libffi' found
  Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
  Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
  to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
  No package 'libffi' found
  Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
  Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
  to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
  No package 'libffi' found
  Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
  Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
  to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
  No package 'libffi' found
  Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
  Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
  to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
  No package 'libffi' found
  c/_cffi_backend.c:15:17: fatal error: ffi.h: No such file or directory
   #include <ffi.h>
                   ^
  compilation terminated.
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/tmp/pip-build-aWg7sM/bcrypt/setup.py", line 240, in <module>
      **keywords_with_side_effects(sys.argv)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 111, in setup
      _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 317, in __init__
      self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs['setup_requires'])
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 372, in fetch_build_eggs
      replace_conflicting=True,
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 846, in resolve
      dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1118, in best_match
      return self.obtain(req, installer)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1130, in obtain
      return installer(requirement)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 440, in fetch_build_egg
      return cmd.easy_install(req)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 699, in easy_install
      return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 725, in install_item
      dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 906, in install_eggs
      return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1145, in build_and_install
      self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1133, in run_setup
      raise DistutilsError("Setup script exited with %s" % (v.args[0],))
  distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for bcrypt
  Running setup.py clean for bcrypt
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-aWg7sM/bcrypt/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" clean --all:
  Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
  Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
  to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
  No package 'libffi' found
  Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
  Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
  to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
  No package 'libffi' found
  Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
  Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
  to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
  No package 'libffi' found
  Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
  Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
  to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
  No package 'libffi' found
  Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
  Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
  to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
  No package 'libffi' found
  c/_cffi_backend.c:15:17: fatal error: ffi.h: No such file or directory
   #include <ffi.h>
                   ^
  compilation terminated.
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/tmp/pip-build-aWg7sM/bcrypt/setup.py", line 240, in <module>
      **keywords_with_side_effects(sys.argv)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 111, in setup
      _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 317, in __init__
      self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs['setup_requires'])
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 372, in fetch_build_eggs
      replace_conflicting=True,
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 846, in resolve
      dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1118, in best_match
      return self.obtain(req, installer)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1130, in obtain
      return installer(requirement)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 440, in fetch_build_egg
      return cmd.easy_install(req)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 699, in easy_install
      return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 725, in install_item
      dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 906, in install_eggs
      return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1145, in build_and_install
      self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1133, in run_setup
      raise DistutilsError("Setup script exited with %s" % (v.args[0],))
  distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed cleaning build dir for bcrypt
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for cffi ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-aWg7sM/cffi/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpC6BW0Mpip-wheel- --python-tag cp27:
  Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
  Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
  to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
  No package 'libffi' found
  Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
  Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
  to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
  No package 'libffi' found
  Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
  Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
  to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
  No package 'libffi' found
  Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
  Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
  to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
  No package 'libffi' found
  Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
  Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
  to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
  No package 'libffi' found
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7
  creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/cffi
  copying cffi/setuptools_ext.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/cffi
  copying cffi/cparser.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/cffi
  copying cffi/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/cffi
  copying cffi/vengine_gen.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/cffi
  copying cffi/recompiler.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/cffi
  copying cffi/verifier.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/cffi
  copying cffi/api.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/cffi
  copying cffi/ffiplatform.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/cffi
  copying cffi/cffi_opcode.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/cffi
  copying cffi/backend_ctypes.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/cffi
  copying cffi/commontypes.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/cffi
  copying cffi/model.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/cffi
  copying cffi/error.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/cffi
  copying cffi/vengine_cpy.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/cffi
  copying cffi/lock.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/cffi
  copying cffi/_cffi_include.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/cffi
  copying cffi/parse_c_type.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/cffi
  copying cffi/_embedding.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/cffi
  copying cffi/_cffi_errors.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/cffi
  running build_ext
  building '_cffi_backend' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7
  creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/c
  arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-Ub3vap/python2.7-2.7.13=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -DUSE__THREAD -DHAVE_SYNC_SYNCHRONIZE -I/usr/include/ffi -I/usr/include/libffi -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c c/_cffi_backend.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/c/_cffi_backend.o
  c/_cffi_backend.c:15:17: fatal error: ffi.h: No such file or directory
   #include <ffi.h>
                   ^
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for cffi
  Running setup.py clean for cffi
Failed to build bcrypt cffi
Installing collected packages: pycparser, cffi, six, bcrypt
  Running setup.py install for cffi ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-aWg7sM/cffi/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-IDU1PT-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=:
    Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'libffi' found
    Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'libffi' found
    Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'libffi' found
    Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'libffi' found
    Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'libffi' found
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7
    creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/cffi
    copying cffi/setuptools_ext.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/cffi
    copying cffi/cparser.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/cffi
    copying cffi/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/cffi
    copying cffi/vengine_gen.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/cffi
    copying cffi/recompiler.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/cffi
    copying cffi/verifier.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/cffi
    copying cffi/api.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/cffi
    copying cffi/ffiplatform.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/cffi
    copying cffi/cffi_opcode.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/cffi
    copying cffi/backend_ctypes.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/cffi
    copying cffi/commontypes.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/cffi
    copying cffi/model.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/cffi
    copying cffi/error.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/cffi
    copying cffi/vengine_cpy.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/cffi
    copying cffi/lock.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/cffi
    copying cffi/_cffi_include.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/cffi
    copying cffi/parse_c_type.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/cffi
    copying cffi/_embedding.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/cffi
    copying cffi/_cffi_errors.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/cffi
    running build_ext
    building '_cffi_backend' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7
    creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/c
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-Ub3vap/python2.7-2.7.13=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -DUSE__THREAD -DHAVE_SYNC_SYNCHRONIZE -I/usr/include/ffi -I/usr/include/libffi -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c c/_cffi_backend.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/c/_cffi_backend.o
    c/_cffi_backend.c:15:17: fatal error: ffi.h: No such file or directory
     #include <ffi.h>
                     ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-aWg7sM/cffi/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-IDU1PT-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-aWg7sM/cffi/
```

I originally was testing my web app on my MacBook but when I upload on to raspbian based server, and try to install from the requirements.txt only brcypt failed to install.

Comment: have you tried installing `libffi libffi-dev` packages?

Comment: yes i tried to install it using apt-get as well pip but did not found in collections

Comment: I think you question is same as this https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37281/cant-install-flask-bcrypt-libffi-is-missing in essence.